# Why selenium scroll is not working on my other computer?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So I have a program that scrapes all of the apartment prices, room and bathroom quantity, address and links from the Zillow page. This program worked fine on my 1st computer, but on my second computer it doesn't scroll the page as it should so it only gives me the first 9 apartments instead of e.g. 20.

What could be the problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import random
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


URL = "https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.52499667529297%2C%22east%22%3A-122.34166232470703%2C%22south%22%3A37.662044543503555%2C%22north%22%3A37.88836615784793%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22days%22%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A12%7D"

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
]

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# TRYING TO ACT LIKE HUMAN
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={random.choice(user_agents)}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(URL)
# AGAIN TRYING TO ACT LIKE HUMAN
time.sleep(random.uniform(5, 10))

# SCROLLING DOWN THE PAGE TO LOAD ALL OF THE APARTMENTS
scroll_increment = 0
while scroll_increment < 1000: 
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {scroll_increment * 10});")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 2))
    scroll_increment += 200

web_page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'lxml')

# ---------------- Prices ---------------- #
prices = soup.find_all("span", class_="PropertyCardWrapper__StyledPriceLine-srp__sc-16e8gqd-1 iMKTKr")
prices_list = [price.getText().split()[0] for price in prices if price.getText().startswith('$')]
#print(prices_list)

# ---------------- Bedrooms and bathrooms ---------------- #
quantities = soup.find_all("ul", class_="StyledPropertyCardHomeDetailsList-c11n-8-84-3__sc-1xvdaej-0 eYPFID")
quantity_list = [
    " ".join(
        q.getText(strip=True)
        for q in quantity.select("li")
        if not q.getText().startswith("--")
    )
    for quantity in quantities
]
#print(quantity_list)

# ---------------- Addresses ---------------- #
adresses = soup.find_all("address")
adresses_list = [adress.getText() for adress in adresses]
#print(adresses_list)

# ---------------- LINKS ---------------- #
links = soup.find_all("a", class_="StyledPropertyCardDataArea-c11n-8-84-3__sc-yipmu-0 jnnxAW property-card-link")
links_clean = [link.get("href") for link in links]
#print(links_clean)


# ---------------- MERGED LIST OF EVERYTHING ---------------- #
merged_list = [[prices_list[i], quantity_list[i], adresses_list[i], links_clean[i]] for i in range(len(prices_list))]


# ---------------- WRITING TO GOOGLE SHEETS ---------------- #
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("client_secret.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("PythonSheets").sheet1

for row_number in range(len(prices_list)):
    sheet.insert_row([prices_list[row_number], quantity_list[row_number], adresses_list [row_number], links_clean[row_number]], 2+row_number)
```

**UPDATE**: I tried it on computer at my job and it worked fine, I don't know why it does not work at my other computer?